# Como customizar emojis (unicode) de uma página?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, css-font-face

Em sistema operacionais Windows ao usar emojis a fonte usadas pelos navegadores **geralmente** é o `Segoe UI Emoji`

> Nota: no Firefox ele possui um proprio "sistema de emojis", creio que ele usa o `Twemoji Mozilla`:
>   - https://github.com/mozilla/twemoji-colr
>
> O que faz o Firefox ter os proprios emojis, sem depender de suporte do sistema operacional

É possível via CSS e fontes externas customizar os emojis de uma página?

Isto é sem usar imagens e afins, a ideia é realmente usar os *emojis unicode*

Comment: @hugocsl é, o mesmo que o "Firefox" faz internamente, aonde ele troca as fontes de emoji no sistema operacional pelas fontes proprias, assim conseguindo dar suporte até para sistemas com "pouco suporte"

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, até tinha montado uma reposta, mas acredito que não era bem o que você pediu. O que você quer é algo como [isso](https://css-tricks.com/emoji-toggles/)?

Comment: @JoãoPedroSchmitz sim eu vi sua resposta e o link que postou agora, mas o que eu quero é **CUSTOMIZAR** e não **USAR** em locais específicos ou ações especificas, assim como no iOS, FF e Windows se olhar os mesmos emojis não aparecem iguais visualmente, a ideia é customizar o visual dos "emojis unicode", estou falando de unicode e de fontes e não de como usar CSS. Aliais eu formulo perguntas assim para criar conteúdo, basta como elas variam visualmente em diferentes sistemas operacionais: https://emojipedia.org/grinning-face/

Comment: Eu tentei usando `@font-face` mas não consegui, a minha ideia era colocar dentro da regra um `font-family: "mesmo nome da font emoji local"` e depois colocar `src: url('http://site/seuEmojiCustomisado.ttf')` mas nos testes que fiz aqui localmente não consegui chegar em um resultado...

Comment: @hugocsl vou te dar uma dica, pesquise por *unicode control character* ou *unicode codepoints*, eu não vou formular uma resposta ainda porque quero dar chance para todos e assim "aquecer o site".

Comment: @JoãoPedroSchmitz o mesmo que eu disse para o hugocsl acima. Vamos aquecer o site :)

Comment: Caramba, muito legal a pergunta! E procurar a resposta me fez aprender [algo novo](https://jsfiddle.net/aetr83cz/) hoje!

Answer (score 1):

Sim! Tem como.

Como você provavelmente já sabe, cada fonte traz pra gente um tipo diferente de emoji.

Você pode procurar qual fonte bate com o tipo de emoji que você quer e fazer isso:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: FonteNoto;
  src: url("https://cdn.rawgit.com/googlei18n/noto-emoji/07ad7f0f/fonts/NotoEmoji-Regular.ttf");
  unicode-range: U+1F600-1FFFF;
}

/* no código acima você chama a fonte */

.fonte01 {
  font-family: Noto;
}

/* nesse acima você define a fonte da div. */
```

daí quando for aplicar, você usa assim:

```html
<div class="fonte01">Noto Emoji Color: </div>
```

créditos ao brother @fernandosavio que nesse [link](https://jsfiddle.net/aetr83cz/) fez esse teste e trouxe conhecimento pra nós.

Comment: Obrigado cara Bianca, mas procuro uma resposta técnica sobre a linguagem CSS e seus recursos, então preciso que esclareça, esse range `U+1F600-1FFFF` vale para todos emojis? Resolve qualquer emoji? Incluindo todos ranges atuais http://unicode.org/emoji/charts/emoji-versions.html?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, emojis com ZWJ não estão nesse intervalo, pois são "letras compostas" de diversos emojis separados pelo "espaço juntador de comprimento zero"